# Experience with SiSense Prism

Tags: bigdata

I'm curious to know what language/technologies makeup the SiSense Prism BI platform. It looks like a very powerful platform having quite the impressive credentials.

[SiSense Website - Prism](http://www.sisense.com/)

Comment: http://www.sisense.com/product/technology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SiSense Prism is coded primarily in C/C++ in the back-end, C# for the desktop tools and JavaScript/HTML5 for the interactive web applications.

There are quite a few unique technologies that are embedded in the Prism suite.Most of these technologies are 'invisible' to you and range from compression algorithms to instruction recycling and CPU-cache awareness (really scary stuff).

These technologies (under their collective name - ElastiCube) enable's Prism most fundamental capability - making terabyte-scale data available for real-time (on-demand) analytics by non-technical users, on a single commodity server.

You can read more about SiSense technology here:  http://www.sisense.com/product/technology

HTH,
Elad Israeli | 
Founder, SiSense

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious that the backend makes intensive use of monetDB:
https://www.monetdb.org

This can be easily observed by inspecting the dlls that come with the package, the data stored on disk and the server's internal connection streams.

Obviously recycling, compression, caching and CPU utilization are techniques used by all professional developers for creating software (monetDB seems to be a good reference), so that's not really unique...